# Cassandra compaction strategy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

We have a big Cassandra cluster 22 Servers (on each server near 20T data )

We recently changed compaction strategy  from SizeTieredCompactionStrategy (STCS) to DateTieredCompactionStrategy (DTCS) .

We store many binary files under our cluster . Then after some time we altered many data.  Then, to free space, we launched compaction .

So after compaction ended  almost all servers freed space . But nodetool status
show that 2 servers still have many duplicated data .

--  Address       Load       Tokens  Owns
UN  1.1.1.1     19.99 TB   256     4.7%
UN  1.1.1.2     18.94 TB   256     4.4%
UN  1.1.1.3     19.55 TB   256     4.5%
**UN  1.1.1.4     28.24 TB   256     4.8%**

**UN  1.1.1.5     23.95 TB   256     4.7%**

For all data we use   gc_grace_seconds=0 AND

So I started compactions once more on this 2 servers . (and its no avail)

nodetool compactionhistory

Looks like for biggest tables

data data1   1441346309116   7694331659     7694326967     {1:25608, 2:138}

Looks like didn't drop any altered data  .

It may be so large difference between servers data storage ? Or its some problem related to strategy change ?

Big thanks for your help .

Comment: Have you tried running nodetool cleanup?

Comment: Hello, first via opscenter . Then via nodetool ... Problem only with 2 servers